# Almost subgroups of $\mathbb S^1$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, additive-combinatorics

Suppose $X\subset \mathbb S^1$ is a finite subset of the group $\mathbb S^1$ such that $|X+X|<(1+c )|X|$ for a sufficiently small $c\in(0,1)$. I believe that in such case there exists a subgroup $G=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb S^1$ such that $n$ is "close" to $|X|$ and the size of the symmetric difference $|X\Delta G|$ is small comparatively to $|X|$. I.e.  informally, $X$ is almost a subgroup of $\mathbb S^1$.

I believe that this should be a classical statement, but don't know how to find it in the literature. Do you know a reference or a short proof? How small is $|X\Delta G|$ comparatively to $|X|$?

Comment: a starting point might be corollary 5.6 of tao-vu, which says that $X \subseteq z+H$ for some $z \in S^1$ and $H \le S^1$ with $|H| < \frac{3}{2}|X|$.

Comment: In any case, "subgroup" should be replaced to "coset"